# PHP Insert Into function only working once?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to write some PHP code that adds data submitted via a form into a database table I have created. It works great - once. Once I have submitted data and added it to the database via the form once already it will no longer work. I'm thinking it's a problem with the function I have written as when using var_dump(); on the variables I'm submitting in the form they all come out fine.

I'd appreciate any suggestions you guys might have, thanks!

```
<form action="" method="post">

            <label for="habbo_name"><center><b>Habbo Name:</b></label><br >               
            <input type="text" name="habbo_name" size="30">

            <b><center>Transfer Status:<br ><select name="transfer_status">
                <option value="Stage Five">Stage Four - Rejected</option>
                <option value="Stage Four">Stage Four - Accepted</option>
                <option value="Stage Three">Stage Three</option>
                <option value="Stage Two">Stage Two</option>
                <option value="Stage One" selected="selected">Stage One</option>
            </select>

            <label for="date"><center><b>Date:</b></label><br >
            <input type="text" name="date" size="30"><br />

            <input type="Submit"><br /><br />

    </form>

    <a href="modtransfers.php">Go back</a>

    <?php     
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
            $habbo_name = $_POST['habbo_name'];
            $transfer_status = $_POST['transfer_status'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];

            add_transfer($habbo_name, $transfer_status, $date);
            header('Location: moderate.php');
            exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Function:

```
function add_transfer($habbo_name, $transfer_status, $date) {
    global $con;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `transfers` SET `habbo_name`='$habbo_name', `transfer_status`='$transfer_status', `date`='$date'";
    $update = $con->prepare($query);
    $update->execute();
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: I've checked via PHPMyAdmin after having submitted the form for a second time and there is no new record added.

Comment: Incidentally, the way you build your query really defeats the purpose of using prepared statements...

Comment: Is the second record different from the first? Can you get php to tell you about any errors? Specifically you do not show how `$con` is set. Could it be that you don't close the database connection before reopening it?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the `create table` statement for `transfers`.

Comment: in case you haven't done so try it with `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` to make it harder to miss sql errors. And your script is still prone to sql injections since you put the payload parameters as string literals in the sql query as Floris pointed out.

Comment: Feel like such a moron. Added that code @VolkerK and realised I hadn't set the primary key properly so it was duplicating. Thanks for your patience dealing with a newb like me guys. Also, thanks Floris for pointing that out. I'm somewhat new to PHP trying to edit code someone else already wrote so I'll look into what I can do to fix it.

Comment: @user3478181 : `Thanks for your patience dealing with a newb like me guys` - compared to what sometimes happens here on SO your code is gold and you finding the error after just a little hint sets you way apart from `newbs` (in case that was meant derogative and not just "new to this subject" ;-) ) | For the sql injection part take a look at https://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements - prepared statements and (named) parameters aren't silver bullets but ...quite close.

Comment: I completely agree with @VolkerK. Welcome to SO and good luck in your learning journey!

Answer (score -1):

You have syntax error in insert query, use it like below

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `transfers` (`habbo_name`,`transfer_status`,`date`) VALUES ('$habbo_name', '$transfer_status', '$date')";
```